# Send messages from a lambda in one account to an SQS in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

For cross-account access of an SQS from a lambda, do I need to allow the IAM role attached to the lambda to have SQS permissions, or allow the IAM role to have permissions in the SQS's Access policy? (or do both?)

Update: Basically I have the SQS Access Policy set up as suggested in some of the answers below.

I am getting a

> `AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue`

when trying to send something to the Queue `(`boto3.resource('sqs').Queue(" some queue_url").send_message(**kwargs))` from the lambda, I am wondering if permissions need to be explicitly added to the IAM role itself to allow to send to the queue.

Code to send to SQS in the lambda (which is in us-west-1) is like:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    boto3.resource('sqs').Queue('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sqs_accnt_num/name_of_sqs').send_message(MessageBody="SomeMessageJSONDUMP")
```

SQS Access Policy is like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
  "Id": "SomeID",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Sid": "somesid",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:sqs_accnt_num:name_of_sqs",
      "Condition": {
         "ArnEquals": {
            "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::lambda_accnt_num:role/name:" 
          } 
       }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "somesid2",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:secureTransport": "false"
         }
      }
  }
]}
```

**Updates: Issue Solved:**

So looks like the issue was in the SQS access policy. For some reason, in my original policy when I had the Condition check like:

```
      "Sid": "somesid",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:sqs_accnt_num:name_of_sqs",
      "Condition": {
         "ArnEquals": {
            "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::lambda_accnt_num:role/name:" 
          } 
       }
```

then, I was still getting an 'Access Denied' error when trying to send the message from the lambda. But as John Rotenstein suggested in his answer, I removed the `Condition` clause entirely and put the iam role arn directly in the Principal like this:

```
      "Sid": "somesid2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::lambda_accnt_num:role/name:"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:sqs_accnt_num:name_of_sqs"
```

**THEN IT WORKED!**
Although the issue is solved, does anyone know why my original policy (with the Condition clause) didn't work? I don't see anything wrong with the policy itself.

One little caveat from John Rotenstein's answer; for cross-region sqs access from a lambda, you will have to add the `region_name` field to denote the region the sqs is in, while creating the sqs_resource, like this:

```
boto3.resource('sqs', region_name='us-east-1')
```

Also if you have encryption enabled in the SQS, make sure your lambda has KMS permissions, and the KMS key that the SQS has is allowed access from the lambda account.

Comment: Yes it is solved see the updates on the question

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are going to to this. One way would be:

- Setup **assumable role** in SQS Acc which can be assumed by a lambda function in different account.
- the function has `assume-role` **permissions** so that it can assume the role from SQS Account.
- the lambda calls `assume-role` to get **temp credentials** to perform actions in the SQS Account.

The other way would be through SQS resource-based policy, which would allow lambda role to submit messages to it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS queues can be given an **Access Policy**.

This policy allows you to grant entities access to the queue, **including entities from other AWS Accounts**.

Therefore, you can simply edit the Access Policy on the SQS queue to permit access from the ARN of the IAM Role being used by the AWS Lambda function.

Here is an example from [Identity and access management in Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-authentication-and-access-control.html):

> The following example Amazon SQS policy gives AWS account 111122223333 permission to send to and receive from queue2 owned by AWS account 444455556666.

```json
{   
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "UseCase1",
   "Statement" : [{
      "Sid": "1", 
      "Effect": "Allow",           
      "Principal": {
         "AWS": [
            "111122223333"
         ]
      },
      "Action": [
         "sqs:SendMessage",
         "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ], 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:444455556666:queue2"  
   }]
}
```

You should be able to change the `Principal` to reference the specific IAM Role being used.

---

**UPDATE:** To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created IAM Role `Role-A` for Lambda in Account-A (Sending account) with `AmazonSQSFullAccess` policy
- Created SQS queue `Queue-B` in Account-B (Receiving account) with Access Policy:

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:Account-B:queue-b"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__sender_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-A:role/role-a"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:Account-B:queue-b"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Created AWS Lambda function `Lambda-A` in Account-A to send a message to `Queue-B`:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    sqs_resource = boto3.resource('sqs')
    queue = sqs_resource.Queue('https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Account-B/queue-b')
    response = queue.send_message(MessageBody="SomeMessageJSONDUMP")
    
    # Debug
    print(response)
```

Debug log entry was:

> {'MD5OfMessageBody': '...', 'MessageId': '...', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '...', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '...', 'date': 'Fri, 30 Jul 2021 23:25:40 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '378'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

The message was successfully received:

[image: SQS queue]

Comment: So ideally, if I already have the SQS Access Policy set up (basically have the Principal set to the arn of the IAM role attached to the lambda in the other account), I don't need to EXPLICITLY state the same SQS permissions in the IAM role?

Comment: I am getting a `AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue` when trying to send something to the Queue 
(`boto3.resource('sqs').Queue(" some queue_url").send_message(**kwargs)`), 

I am wondering if permissions need to be explicitly added to the IAM role itself to allow to send to the queue.

Comment: It is saying that the Queue URL isn't correct. It _might_ be because it is in a different account, but that shouldn't matter. It is similar to this: [SQS Cross Account Access | Trend Micro](https://www.cloudconformity.com/knowledge-base/aws/SQS/sqs-cross-account-access.html). Are you sure you are using the Queue URL and _not_ the Queue ARN?

Comment: No, I am pretty sure I am using the correct Queue URL.

Comment: Can you possible add your code and the policy to your Question? Feel free to hide your Account ID. Which reminds me -- make sure you are using the correct Account ID in the Queue URL

Comment: Hey John, please see the updated question I put the SQS Access Policy and the lambda code there. Yep using correct Account ID.
Note: The lambda is in one account in west, and the SQS is in another account in east. So it is cross-region as well as cross-account transfer

Comment: It worked for me! I have added details of how I recreated the scenario. Admittedly, I did it in the same region, but I don't _think_ that should matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped solve my issue. I put some updates on the question, in case you know why the original solution I had wasnt working!